# foreground Service recursively calls new activity and cant be stopped

Tags: android, quickblox, foreground-service

I am working on Integrating a [Quickblox](http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-videochat-android) based video chat into my app. 
 Here i am running a listener in foreground service which listens to the video call initiated by opponent.  here in switch statement, at call accept state i am calling a new activity which is nothing but a dialler screen with accept and disconnect button. accept button connects the call but disconnect cuts the call and closes the activity, but again the same activity (dialler screen) opens repeatedly after multiple times, My question is how to make service to call once and ignore the rest calls if its disconnected. (Am sending reject signal to opponent thus call drops from opponent but here service calls activity repeatedly though call is dropped from opponent)

Here is the code
    **VchatListener service with OnQBVideoChatListener with switch statement has a accept call state which calls new activity**

```
public class VChatListener extends Service {
    private VideoChatConfig videoChatConfig;
    private CallState state;
    QBUser a=DataHolder.getInstance().getCurrentQbUser();
    /* private AlertDialog alertDialog;*/
    private static final int notif_id=1;


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        this.startForeground();
    }

    private void startForeground() {
            startForeground(notif_id, getMyActivityNotification(""));
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //startForeground(FOREGROUND_ID, notification);

         Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {               

              @Override
              public void run() {



                  try {
                    Log.i("******Service Call user Here","now*******");
                    if(a!=null){
                    Log.i("******Service testing",""+a);
                    }else{
                        Log.i("******Service testing user","nothing");
                    }
                        Log.i("***Still","running****");
                      QBVideoChatController.getInstance().setQBVideoChatListener(a, qbVideoChatListener);
                  } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
                      ex.printStackTrace();
                  } catch (XMPPException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }
              };
         };
            new Thread(runnable).start();


            return Service.START_REDELIVER_INTENT;

    private OnQBVideoChatListener qbVideoChatListener = new OnQBVideoChatListener() {

        @Override
        public void onVideoChatStateChange(CallState state, VideoChatConfig receivedVideoChatConfig) {
            Debugger.logConnection("onVideoChatStateChange: " + state);
            videoChatConfig = receivedVideoChatConfig;
            /*if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }*/

            Log.i("service state",""+state.toString());
            switch (state) {
                case ACCEPT:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(VChatListener.this, CallActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    intent.putExtra(VideoChatConfig.class.getCanonicalName(), videoChatConfig);
                    startActivity(intent);
                   // showCallDialog();
                    Log.i("service state 1",""+state.toString());

                    break;
                case ON_ACCEPT_BY_USER:
                    Log.i("service state 2",""+state.toString());

                   /* QBVideoChatController.getInstance().onAcceptFriendCall(videoChatConfig, null);*/

                    //startVideoChatActivity();
                    break;
                case ON_REJECTED_BY_USER:
                    Log.i("service state 3",""+state.toString());
                       /*Toast.makeText(VChatListener.this, "Rejected by user", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                    break;
                case ON_DID_NOT_ANSWERED:
                    Log.i("service state 4",""+state.toString());

                   /* Toast.makeText(VChatListener.this, "User did not answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                    break;
                case ON_CANCELED_CALL:
                    videoChatConfig = null;
                    Log.i("service state 5","nothing");

                    /*if (alertDialog != null && alertDialog.isShowing()){
                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    autoCancelHandler.removeCallbacks(autoCancelTask);*/
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    public void onDestroyed(){
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private Notification getMyActivityNotification(String text){
        // The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects
        // this notification
        CharSequence title = getText(R.string.title_activity);
      /*  PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0, new Intent(this,Appointment.class), 0);*/

        return new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(text)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .getNotification();     
}


}
```

Here is the activity which will be called by service the end button associated with function end, disconnects the call.

```
public class CallActivity extends Activity {
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private VideoChatConfig videoChatConfig;
    private VChatListener vChatListener;
    QBUser qbuser;
    MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_call);

        ImageButton b1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        ImageButton b2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        playRingtone();

        /*while(!b1.isPressed() || !b2.isPressed()){
        playRingtone();
        }*/

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.please_wait));
        progressDialog
                .setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        // TODO add stopCalling here, send Cancel message if
                        // need
                        // XMPPSender.sendCancelCallMsg(videoChatConfig);
                        // QBVideoChatController.getInstance().stopCalling();
                    }
                });

        qbuser = DataHolder.getInstance().getCurrentQbUser();
        videoChatConfig = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(
                VideoChatConfig.class.getCanonicalName());
        ;

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                onAcceptCallClick();
                mMediaPlayer.stop();
            }

            private void onAcceptCallClick() {
                //mMediaPlayer.stop();
                QBVideoChatController.getInstance().acceptCallByFriend(
                        videoChatConfig, null);
                startVideoChatActivity();

            }

            private void startVideoChatActivity() {
                if (videoChatConfig.getCallType() == CallType.VIDEO_AUDIO) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                            ActivityVideoChat.class);
                    intent.putExtra(VideoChatConfig.class.getCanonicalName(),
                            videoChatConfig);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else if(videoChatConfig.getCallType() == CallType.AUDIO) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                            ActivityAudioChat.class);
                    intent.putExtra(VideoChatConfig.class.getCanonicalName(),
                            videoChatConfig);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }

        });

    }

     public void end(View view)
        {
         mMediaPlayer.stop();
            QBVideoChatController.getInstance().finishVideoChat(videoChatConfig);
            XMPPSender.sendCancelCallMsg(videoChatConfig);
            QBVideoChatController.getInstance().stopCalling(); 
            super.onDestroy();
            finish();
        }

    public void playRingtone() {

        try {
               Uri alert =  RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
              mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
              mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, alert);
              final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
             if (audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING) != 0) {
             mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
             mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
             mMediaPlayer.prepare();
             mMediaPlayer.start();
            }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   

    /*  try {
            Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(),
                    notification);
            r.play();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/
    }
}
```

to limit the service to call activity once i included in manifest launch mode = "singleTask" which launches activity once, but when activity get closed by disconnect it is called again and doesnt stop.

```
  <activity
        android:name="com.yugays.videochatsample.ui.CallActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
    </activity>
```

**How to stop activity getting created after call is disconnected and activity is closed**.

Comment: hi akash i am facing same quickblox issue how did you handle this process ?